# Erratic behavior of Django with environment string

Tags: python, django

My settings.py has this:

```
DEBUG = os.environ.get('MY_VAR', True)
print(DEBUG)
```

I set MY_VAR from command line in one of the following ways, doesn't matter which, outcome is the same:

```
export MY_VAR='False' 
export MY_VAR=False
```

When I start my server... I am outputted:

```
False
False
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
May 26, 2017 - 17:50:44
Django version 1.11, using settings 'my_app.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

However, the application will **always** run in debug mode. I know that because of the yellow error screens I get along with the indication at the bottom that the app is in debug mode.

It is in debug mode Unless I explicitly define this:

```
DEBUG = False
```

I have no idea on even how to begin explaining this. I need my application to decide to run in debug mode or not based on an environment string, not explicit defining in `settings.py`.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `'False'` is not the same as `False`; the string `'False'` is truth-y, because it's not the empty string `''`.

Comment: still. same results whether I use 'False' or False

Comment: Because either way your program gets a *string*; try printing the `repr` of the value, `print(repr(DEBUG))`.

Comment: You were right. it was strings no matter how I defined it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading from `os.environ` returns a string. You need to retreive the appropriate boolean from the string using say a dictionary.

```
dct = {'True': True, 'False': False}
my_var = os.environ.get('MY_VAR')
DEBUG = dct.get(my_var, True) # Turn returned string to boolean
```